# OS X 10.10 hard-coded absolute paths to network home directory

Tags: mac-osx, nfs, osx-yosemite

We have our users home directories on NFS servers.  In the past, when we used 10.7, this was just a little problematic... every now and then, either from someone logging in at two different machines at the same time or "just because", mail or calendars would get corrupted, and we could fix that.  Now we're at 10.10, and a lot of things are remembering hard-coded paths to /Network/Servers/homeserver/home/username  This becomes REALLY problematic when we move a user to a new NFS server.  Some users are unable to log on, getting very generic messages about "cant find home directory".  And some of them can log on It looks like something or several somethings in the user's home directory are keeping this path.

I've been wiping out (in the user home directory):
.SpotlightV100
Library/Logs/*
Library/Containers/*
Library/Caches/*
Library/Saved Application State/*
Library/Preferences/ByHost/*

Anyone know of anything else, probably in Library/Preferences, that's saving this stuff?  It isn't in the human-readable plists, or the output of 'strings' from any of the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the location of a home folder, especially a network home folder, is a non trivial task. I am assuming it only comes up infrequently. In the past we have found the simplest and most effective solution is to delete the entire ~/Library folder on the server and allow a fresh one to be recreated at the next login. Your users will loose some settings, preferences, and most important to our users, their browser bookmarks. We usually restore these items on request from a backup or reconfigure things like the Mail.app manually for them. Mac Network homes are notoriously finicky and we even need to do this for some users after an OS upgrade.